# Selenoid browser session not getting created

Tags: automated-tests, selenoid, browser-testing

I have successfully installed Selenoid on my Mac and can view the ui, but when I try run the tests I get "Requested environment is not available" error and I even can't create the sessions manually

[ui screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB8PP.png)

I have the browsers.json file in config folder and the permissions seem correct. What I might be doing wrong? Could it have something to do with the browser docker image?

$ docker pull selenoid/firefox:88.0. (from Selenoid official site)

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Check that browsers.json contains browser version you are requesting. Also Firefox does not support "latest" as version because this is rejected by Geckodriver.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing version from latest to a number for Firefox fixed the issue.